# Grails passing params in controllers to selectBox

Tags: grails, select, param

Hey. I have this controller:

```
def participated_favourite = {

        def user = User.get(1)
        def conferenceUser

        def original = ConferenceUser.findAllByUser(user)
        def temp = ConferenceUser.findAllByUserAndIsFavourite(user, 1) // all conferenceUser filtered by User

        def priz = [:]
        def subm = [:]

  ...
  ...

  [temp: temp, priz: priz, subm: subm, orig: original]
}
```

I want now to be able to select in a selectBox, the list of conferences passed by 'original' (in the participated_favourite.gsp).

How can i do that?

```
<g:select name="" from="${orig.list()}" optionKey="id" value=""  />
```

This is giving me an empty select box which shouldnt. because there is one record in my database. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advances,

---

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

I have in same gsp the folowing:

```
<g:each var="it" in="${orig}">
 <table cellspacing="2">
                <tbody><tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
         </tr>
                    <tr>
                   <td class="color1">${it.conference}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
   </g:each>
```

And it is p+rinting the values. So i dont know what is the problem in the select..

Comment: Are you that `original` has values in it?

Comment: i edited the original post. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the `name` attribute a value.

---EDIT -----

Try the following to troubleshoot:

Does this work?

`<g:select from="${ConferenceUser.list()}" />`

If so, how about this?

`<g:select from="${ConferenceUser.list()}" optionKey="id" />`

Comment: hm i can't believe i lost so many time on this stupied issue... The problem was, i was an empty toString() method in the class "conferenceUser". Don't need to say anything more -.- That's for your help and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<g:select name="" from="${orig}" optionKey="id" value=""  />
```

Comment: try printing ${orig} in gsp. Does it prints the value you are looking for?